# sql server split name

Tags: sql-server

i just want to ask how to split name using SQL Server 2008. i found this code 
[Split Name](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/split-name.aspx)

here's the code

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(Leadname, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', Leadname) - 1, -1)) AS [FirstName],
 SUBSTRING(Leadname, CHARINDEX(' ', Leadname) + 1, LEN(Leadname)) AS [LastName]
 FROM Customer
```

lets say that the data is "John Doe", and using that query, the output like this :

```
   First Name    Last Name
   John          Doe
```

but in my Customer Table, i have Leadname only one word like John. Using that query, i get the result like this :

```
   First Name   Last Name
   NULL         John
```

all i want, if i only have one word in my Leadname, the result is

```
   First Name   Last Name
   John         NULL
```

what should i do to make it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING(Name, 1, case when CHARINDEX(' ', Name) = 0 then LEN(Name) else CHARINDEX(' ', Name) end) AS [FirstName],
 case when CHARINDEX(' ', Name) = 0 then null else  SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)) end
 AS [LastName]
 FROM (
    select 'jon doe' Name
    union 
    select 'jon'
 ) X
```

Results:

```
FirstName LastName
--------- --------
jon       doe
jon       NULL

(2 row(s) affected)
```

You could do it a bit cleaner albeit slightly less efficiently with a [user defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your help. it works in my table. once again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split a FullName into existing rows, you can use the update statement below.

```
update Customer    
set FirstName = SUBSTRING([FullName],1,CHARINDEX(' ',[FullName]))
set LastName = SUBSTRING([FullName],CHARINDEX(' ',[FullName]),LEN([FullName]))
```